# Не отображаются лайк-шары в блоке "Поделиться" у facebook

Tags: javascript, facebook, share, ya-share2

Блок обновлен, прошло более 2 дней с момент последнего клика по facebook.
Пример, страницы https://news.pressfeed.ru/10-luchshix-professionalnyx-tem-wordpress-dlya-bloga/

У facebook, после обновления страницы значения лайка не отображается: http://joxi.ru/Dr8ZvR1UoJLoq2

Comment: Не понятна суть вопроса. Если вы являетесь автором страницы, покажите код, в котором у вас определен код для обновления лайков.

Comment: Dred вы являетесь  разработчком блога Поделиться https://tech.yandex.ru/share/  ?  Верстка расположения блока:      <script src="//yastatic.net/es5-shims/0.0.2/es5-shims.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//yastatic.net/share2/share.js"></script> 
    <div class="ya-share2" data-services="collections,vkontakte,facebook,odnoklassniki,moimir"></div>

Comment: нет, я не являются разработчиком этого блога.

Answer (score 0):

Мы разобрались в ситуации. Дело оказалось в том, что Фейсбук в одностороннем порядке обратнонесовместимо обновил API — и теперь получить счетчик можно только получив для своего приложения токен.

Мы со своей стороны обновили код и документацию (ранее токен не был обязательным параметром).

Решение следующее:

1) Добавить приложение фейсбука для свего проекта тут: https://developers.facebook.com/apps/ .

2) Получить токен в соответствие с документацией: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens?locale=en_US#apptokens .

3) В блоке поделяшек добавить атрибут data-access-token:facebook с полученным выше токеном.

Прочитать подробнее можно у нас в документации: https://yandex.ru/dev/share/doc/dg/add-docpage/ в разделе про поддерживаем атрибуты. Там же вы найдёте необходимые ссылки на документацию от FB.

После этого счётчик снова начнёт работать.